# Permanently highlight the month in dates of the form yyyymmdd in vim?

Tags: vim

Using vim, I want to highlight the middle part (`mm`) of `yyyymmdd` in a different color.

For example

20010101 should be highlighted as 2001**01**01

and

20101010 should be highlighted as 2010**10**10.

I was able to highlight the whole date by including the following lines into my .exrc file:

```
highlight yyyymmdd ctermbg=green guibg=green
match yyyymmdd /\(19\|20\)\d\d\(0[1-9]\|1[012]\)\(0[1-9]\|[12][0-9]\|3[01]\)/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match yyyymmdd /\(19\|20\)\d\d\(0[1-9]\|1[012]\)\(0[1-9]\|[12][0-9]\|3[01]\)/
autocmd InsertEnter * match yyyymmdd /\(19\|20\)\d\d\(0[1-9]\|1[012]\)\(0[1-9]\|[12][0-9]\|3[01]\)\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match yyyymmdd /\(19\|20\)\d\d\(0[1-9]\|1[012]\)\(0[1-9]\|[12][0-9]\|3[01]\)/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```

But I haven't figured out how to only highlight the `mm` of `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: Just like you did for the whole date, with an appropriate pattern.

Comment: I want to highlight only part of the pattern, i.e. i want to highlight the 12 in 19991231  but not in 99991299

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:h \zs` and `:h \ze` to highlight only part of a pattern. For example,

```
highlight yyyymmdd ctermbg=green guibg=green
match yyyymmdd /\(19\|20\)\d\{2}\zs\d\{2}\ze\d\{2}/
```